# Why is the etale fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^n$ trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fundamental-groups, etale-cohomology

For $n=1$, one just uses the Riemann-Hurwtiz formula. I am curious about how to do it for $n\geq 2$. I spoke to a colleague and their proof did not click with me and I've since forgotten how it goes.

I know there is an immediate way of seeing it is trivial by using the Riemann Existence Theorem, but I'd like to avoid passing to the complex side of things.

So basically, what is a direct proof that $\pi_1^{et}(\mathbb{P}^n)=1$?

Comment: You probably need the base field to be algebraically closed, or at least separably closed. Possibly of characteristic zero, as I dimly recall that the line is not simply connected in characteristic $p$ (although I’m not sure)…

Comment: @Aphelli You might be right. In this case, I'm really interested only in the case of $k$ algebraically closed.

Comment: If you suppose the existence of a connected etale cover $\pi:X \to \mathbb P^n$, you can look at the vector bundle $\pi_* \mathcal O_X$ and the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\pi)$ thereupon. I'm not sure if this will work in full generality, but morally I think the result follows from the non-existence of torsion line bundles on $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: The name is "Hurwitz". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be proven by induction. The base case is $n=1$ which follows from the Riemann-Hurwitz formula as you describe in your post.

For the inductive step, suppose $f:X\to\Bbb P^n_k$ is a nontrivial etale cover with $X$ connected. Let $H\subset\Bbb P^n_k$ be a hyperplane, and consider $X\times_{\Bbb P^n} H\to H$, a finite etale cover of $H\cong\Bbb P^{n-1}_k$. I claim that $X\times_{\Bbb P^n} H$ is connected: $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n_k}(1)$ is ample on $X$ because $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n_k}(1)$ is ample and $f$ is finite surjective (ref [0B5V](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B5V)), and then $X\times_{\Bbb P^n_k} H$ is the support of this ample divisor inside a nice variety of dimension $\geq 2$ hence connected (ref [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868990/complete-intersections-are-connected) or Hartshorne corollary III.7.9). By the inductive hypothesis, $X\times_{\Bbb P^n} H\to H$ is of degree 1, hence $X\to\Bbb P^n$ must also be of degree one, or an isomorphism.

Comment: Just a small question: what is $X\times_{\mathbb{P}^n} H\rightarrow H$ being of degree $1$ mean and how does this imply $X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ is of degree $1$? 

I suspect you might mean that the degree of the pullback of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_H(1)$ is degree $1$, but I could be wrong. Or do you mean the size of the fibres?

Comment: I mean "degree one" in all the ways one could mean degree one - the scheme theoretic fibers over any point have degree one (i.e. they're 0-dimensional schemes with global sections a 1-dimensional vector space over the base field), the induced morphism on function fields is a degree one extension, etc. (Actually, I'm not talking about the degree of the pullback sheaf - that's usually constructed relative to some ample line bundle and that's extra data we don't have here.)

Comment: I do not think I follow the $1$-dimensional vector space part correctly. How does that holding for $X\times H\rightarrow H$ imply the same for $X\rightarrow P^n$? Is this just some sort of base change application?

Comment: The fiber of the map $X\times_{\Bbb P^n} H\to H$ over a point $p\in H$ is the same as the fiber of the map $X\to\Bbb P^n$ over $p$. But $H$ was an arbitrary hyperplane, so this condition hold everywhere on $\Bbb P^n$. Now, if $A\to B$ is a map of reduced rings so that the induced map $A/\mathfrak{m}A \to B/\mathfrak{m}B$ is an isomorphism for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$, the map $A\to B$ must be an isomorphism, and so $X\to\Bbb P^n$ must be an isomorphism because it's an isomorphism locally. (Recall $X$ and $\Bbb P^n$ are both integral since they're smooth $/k$.)

Comment: (Last comment may need a little adjustment - the point is the map $A\to \prod_{\mathfrak{m}\subset A} A/\mathfrak{m}$ is an injection for the sorts of rings we care about in this problem (fg reduced $k$-algebras), so isomorphism on all residue fields implies isomorphism.)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: why did we need the whole degree $1$ business? Very roughly: finite and etale are preserved by base change so $p_2:X\times_{\mathbb{P}^n}H\rightarrow H$ is an etale covering. Since the fibres are the same as that of $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, the fibres of $p_2$ are singleton. But then that means $p_2$ is an isomorphism (modulo business regarding scheme structures).

Comment: That's what the degree one business *is*. You've just given a slightly different final explanation than you asked for and got earlier in the comments.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the clarification.